# How to get the average for each "type" within a column while ignoring the ones with the same user ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, an events table, and a users table.

```
events table:
id | event_type | user_id
--------------------------
1  | 'type 1'   | 1
2  | 'type 1'   | 1
3  | 'type 1'   | 4
4  | 'type 1'   | 4
5  | 'type 1'   | 3
6  | 'type 2'   | 1
7  | 'type 4'   | 2
```

```
users table:
id | username
---------------
1  | user1
2  | user2
3  | user3
```

I am trying to grab the `AVERAGE` of all event types from **all** users except for 1 specific user.
So looking at the example table I gave above, if `type 1` shows up 5x between 3 unique users but I want to ignore `user_id = 3`, it will then show up a total of 4x between 2 users so the average for `type 1` would be 2. I would need this for every type.

This is the SQL query that I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id = events.user_id
WHERE users.username != 'a username'
```

This only grabs all the events except for the given username. But now I need to find the average for ALL event types.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: What are you counting? The number of users? If so, you'll need to SELECT events.id, COUNT(users.id) AS user_count, don't forget to GROUP BY events.id. Read more here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/

Comment: Okay maybe not count

Comment: Do you need an output set like `Type 1 -> 0.71, Type 2 -> 0.14, Type 4 -> 0.14` ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yup. Whilst ignoring the username inputted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need `events` table and `event_type` column of it to get the desired set :

```
select event_type, (count(*)::float/(select count(*) from events)) as average_nr_of_types
  from events
 group by event_type
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2a5a84b1e0ea7d9cc410f7bc761e7462)</kbd>

Comment: I do need the user table because I need to ignore a specific user.

Comment: After editing with the code, i was able to get it working(I think!) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way with a little adjustment of your query

```
    SELECT event_type, count(distinct events.user_id)
    FROM events
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON users.id = events.user_id
    WHERE users.username != 'a username'
group by event_type
```

Comment: This doesnt fully encapsulate what I am looking for.

Comment: Amended my answer, sssyn, per event_type, you need a count right?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh you're after the average.. Try this

```
SELECT e.event_type, COUNT(e.user_id) / COUNT(DISTINT e.user_id) [AverageUsers]
    FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id
    WHERE u.username != 'a username'
GROUP BY e.event_type;
```

Please note that this will give a whole number as the average because we're dividing integers by integers. If you want a decimal average you'll need to do the below:

```
SELECT e.event_type, COUNT(e.user_id) / (COUNT(DISTINT e.user_id) * 1.0) [AverageUsers]
    FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id
    WHERE u.username != 'a username'
GROUP BY e.event_type;
```

Comment: Hmmm, running your query gives me "1.0" for each type. I had to remove the `[AverageUsers]` as my pgAdmin was throwing an error.